# OutOfMemoryException trying to write Xml from DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset, out-of-memory

In C# i'm trying to get the xml string from a big DataSet:

```
private string GetXmlFromDecomposedPortfolio(string dataSetName, DecomposedPortfolio ptf)
{
     StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

     System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet(dataSetName);

     ds.Tables.Add(ptf.Security.Copy());   
     ds.WriteXml((TextWriter)writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);

     return writer.ToString();
}
```

but i've got the exception:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.     
    at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)    
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)    
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char value)     at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(Char value)  
    at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)   
    at System.Data.DataTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)  
    at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.XmlDataRowWriter(DataRow row, String encodedTableName)  
    at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.Save(XmlWriter xw, Boolean writeSchema)    
    at System.Data.DataSet.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer, XmlWriteMode mode)   
    at System.Data.DataSet.WriteXml(TextWriter writer, XmlWriteMode mode)    
    at Decompose.Library.Render.GetXmlFromDecomposedPortfolio(String dataSetName, DecomposedPortfolio ptf)   
    at Decompose.Library.Render.SavePE()  
    at Decompose.Library.WorkFlow.ProcessBatch()
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Managed code solutions that use classes from the System.Data or System.Xml name may encounter a System.OutOfMemoryException when working with large datasets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/10/10/stringbuilder-outofmemoryexception.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First you create huge (apparently) xml data

`ds.WriteXml((TextWriter)writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);`

After clone it, into the `string` object `writer.ToString();`, so you almost double the memory you need.

What you *can* do, is to create `XML` row-per-row, so create kind of `XmlDataSetRowEnumerator`, that retrieves `XML-per-row` and `yield return`s the resulting `XML`.

Comment: And what about splitting the dataset in different ones?